# Job DSL Plugin - Invoke Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to invoke *Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild Begin Analysis* and *Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild End Analysis* in Jenkins job using *Job DSL Plugin* Script.

I want to produce a **config.xml** like below :

```
<hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerBegin plugin="sonar@2.6">
  <projectKey>a</projectKey>
  <projectName>b</projectName>
  <projectVersion>c</projectVersion>
  <additionalArguments></additionalArguments>
</hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerBegin>

<hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerEnd plugin="sonar@2.6"/>
```

I used folloing DSL snipped, but it is failing with "signature error"

```
    msBuildSQRunnerBegin {
        additionalArguments('')
        msBuildScannerInstallationName('')
        projectKey('TinyJSON')
        projectName('Tiny Json')
        projectVersion('1.0')
        sonarInstallationName('')
    }
    msBuild {
        buildFile('TinyJSON.sln')
    }
    msBuildSQRunnerEnd()
```

Error

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 17) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.msBuildSQRunnerBegin() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure8) values: [script$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure8@6a96899c]
```

Would anyone please help me with DSL script that could generate this snippet in job XML

Comment: we are not a code writing service. We are problem solver if you get stuck with a specific programming challenge.

Comment: Job DSL is by far the best documented Jenkins plugin. Read the comprehensive documentation and use the API viewer, which is filled with examples.

Comment: So whats stopping you?

Comment: @pczeus -  i have updated the question

Comment: Same for me, `No signature of method: java.lang.String.call()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works for me. The script uses the [Automatically Generated DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Automatically-Generated-DSL) which is only available when running the "Process Job DSLs" build step in Jenkins.

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    msBuildSQRunnerBegin {
      additionalArguments('')
      msBuildScannerInstallationName('')
      projectKey('TinyJSON')
      projectName('Tiny Json')
      projectVersion('1.0')
      sonarInstallationName('')
    }
    msBuild {
      buildFile('TinyJSON.sln')
    }
    msBuildSQRunnerEnd()
  }
}
```